# C.walls and Roads missing from Game.structures

Tags: screeps

I'm not sure if I am missing something, but roads and constructed walls are not appearing in Game.structures while ramparts and extensions show up fine. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.
Here is the code i am using

```
for(var i in Game.structures){
 var struct = Game.structures[i];    
 var type =  struct.structureType;
 console.log(type);
```

}

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation. [`Game.structures`](http://screeps.com/docs/Game.php#structures) contains your structures. Walls and roads do not belong to any user, this is why they are not present there.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this got me confused too. As the developer has mentioned, roads and walls aren't inherently "yours" (or anyone elses), so they are not present in the lists where you usually find *your* structures.

This is an example of how you can find all the roads and walls in a room:

```
var allRoadsAndWalls = creep.room.find(Game.STRUCTURES, {filter:function(structure) {
    return structure.structureType == "road" || structure.structureType == "constructedWall";
}});
```